# How to use reduce to test an array for the Math.max function

Tags: javascript, arrays, range, max, reduce

I have an array produced by a range(i, (i + j)) function which uses two counters i and j.  The range function works well to produce an array of the type [3, 4, 5, 6]

Once this array is produced, I would like to point to object 3, 4, 5, and 6 in another array called y.

Within each of the objects pointed to, the key I want the value of is called 'weight'.

I want to use Math.max to return the one with the largest weight.

Can someone please help me, I am new to JavaScript and am not very good at this.

Thank you.

I tried the following code, but it gives an error

```
var m = Math.min(   (   y[range(i, (i + j))].weight   )
)
console.log(m)
```

The error given is "cannot read property 'weight' of undefined".  It's because the range function returns an array of the numbers I want to test so it's trying to process it as:

```
var m = Math.min(   (   y[[3, 4, 5, 6]].weight   )
)
console.log(m)
```

instead of the following, which I would like to see:

```
var m = Math.min(   (   y[3].weight   ), (   y[4].weight   ), (   y[5].weight   ),  (   y[6].weight   )
)
console.log(m)
```

Would using reduce() be appropriate in helping the code sequentially run each number in the returned array from range function, and if so, how could reduce() be implemented?

Thanks so much, I really appreciate it.

Comment: `Math.min(...y.slice(3,7).map(({weight}) => weight))` ?

Comment: If this your question has been answered, please mark it as closed.

Comment: I updated the question to incorporate the suggestions given.  It's giving a new error that it "cannot read property 'lentils' of undefined"

Comment: @tonypizza - Right now, your `if` and `else` statements are having the same exact statement, and your `else` should have a `==` instead of `=`. By using `slice()` inside a `for` loop, you are dealing with data only available so far. Most likely you don't need to put `slice()` in a `for` loop. Check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/57742901/2924577.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I've posted the working code above in Update 2.  If you could take a look at it and show me how to implement the spread and slice functions to nest the loop I would really appreciate it.  Thanks, thank you

Comment: Hi @tonypizza, I looked at Update 2. What is the purpose of those `if` statements if you just want to do `y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts` in both `if` and `else`? In such case, it doesn't matter if `if` evaluates to true or false, the result is just the same. Also, it is unclear what you are trying to evaluate in `if` without knowing more about your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead coupled with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), like so:

```
const min = Math.min( ...( range(i, i+j).map(i => y[i].weight) ) );
```

The **map** operator will create a new array with the result of the callback function, and the **spread** syntax (those `...`) will *'spread'* the array values as if they were arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `range(i, i+j)` function if you just want to use it to access the `y` array.

You can use JavaScript's [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method to create a new array from `y` array between indices `i` and `i+j+1`.

```
var y2 = y.slice(i, i+j+1);
```

Now, you can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to create a new array with just `weight` properties from each object of `y2` array.

```
var weights = y2.map(obj => obj.weight);
```

To find the minimum of these weights, you can use JavaScript's [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) function. [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can be used to pass the weights array as argument to Math.min() function.

```
var min = Math.min(...weights);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var y = [
  {"weight": 100, "a": 1, "b": 2},
  {"weight": 200, "a": 1, "b": 2},
  {"weight": 300, "a": 1, "b": 2},
  {"weight": 400, "a": 1, "b": 2},
  {"weight": 500, "a": 1, "b": 2}
 ]; 

var i = 1, j= 2; // Values used in your range() function.

var y2 = y.slice(i, i+j+1);

var weights = y2.map(obj => obj.weight);

console.log("All weights: " + weights);

var min = Math.min(...weights);

console.log("Minimum weight: " + min);
```